# How do i generate random polygons?

Tags: java, random, shapes, jgrasp

The cell displays 100 random pentagons. 
The pentagons need to be drawn at random locations within the cell, and be entirely inside the cell. 
The pentagons are also drawn in random colors. 
The pentagons have a random dimensions.

that is what i need to match i have no idea where to begin im new to programming

And im using JGrasp I appreciate the help!

Comment: This seems like homework. You should start with google :-)
When you've put some effort into your problem but you still have difficulties, add some code and show us which part(s) you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Start simply.  Write the code to draw a single pentagon within the given cell.  Test and correct your code.  Then add code to colour in your pentagon.  Again test and correct.  Extend your code to draw five randomly coloured pentagons.  Test, correct and extend to 100 pentagons.  If you get completely stuck then ask your instructor or post your code so far here with your question.  Showing code will get a much better response.

You might need to ask your instructor if the pentagons are allowed to overlap or not.